# How to mark .NET objects exposed to COM-interop as single threaded?

Tags: c#, .net, com, multithreading, com-interop

When defining a COM-visible class in C++ I can define the supported threading model in the header file (the `threading(single)` line):

```
[
    coclass,
    default(IComInterface),
    threading(single),
    vi_progid("Example.ComClass"),
    progid("Example.ComClass.1"),
    version(1.0),
    uuid("72861DF5-4C77-43ec-A4DC-ED04396F0CCD")
]
```

Is there a comparable way of setting the threading model in .NET (for example an attribute)? I currently define my COM-class as such:

```
[Guid("67155A91-2948-43f5-B07F-5C55CDD240E5")]
[ComVisible(true)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface IComInterface
{
    ...
}


[Guid("DC5E6955-BB29-44c8-9FC0-6AADEEB2AFFB")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ProgId("Example.ComClass")]
public class ComClass : IComInterface
{
    ...
}
```

**--edit:**

The comments on the marked answer are the really important thing. It seems like the only way to tell RegAsm to set a different ThreadingModel is to write a custom registration method marked with the `[ComRegisterFunction]`attribute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's really obscure, I've never seen the "threading" attribute in MIDL.   Nor have the [MSDN Library authors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367088%28VS.85%29.aspx).

A COM coclass publishes its threading requirements in the registry, using the `HKCR\CLSID\{guid}\InProcServer32` key.  The ThreadingModel value declares the apartment it needs.  If it is missing or is set to "Apartment" then is announces that is not thread-safe and requires help from an STA thread.  CoCreateInstance() uses this value when it creates the object.  If necessary it will start an STA thread and create a proxy if the current thread is not STA, ensuring it is always used in a thread-safe way.

A [ComVisible] .NET class will be registered as "Both", indicating that it is okay to be used on a thread in the MTA.  Pretty optimistic, but follows the .NET philosophy that everything is thread-unsafe but can be made safe by putting the `lock` keyword in the right places.  A promise that is not often tested btw, risky.  Overriding the ThreadingModel value (or omitting it) requires writing code to register the coclass yourself, decorated with the [ComRegisterFunction] attribute.  RegistrationServices.RegisterTypeForComClients() can be useful to get the basic keys into place.

Comment: I think the OP is not talking about MIDL attributes. http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/zfbxt3zs.aspx

Comment: I just checked the registry and the current value for ThreadingModel is "Both", which isn't the one I'm looking for. Isn't there another way of setting the ThreadingModel besides manually registering the COM-classes using a method marked with [ComRegisterFunction] ?

Comment: I found additional information in the MSDN (under "COM Client and Windows Server 2003": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eaw10et3(VS.80).aspx) telling me, that the default ThreadingModel for .NET COM-servers registered by RegAsm is in fact "Both". So is there no other way of telling RegAsm to use another ThreadingModel besides writing a register method of my own?

Comment: No, you'll have to write a [ComRegisterFunction].

Comment: Here is an example of a ComRegisterFunction to set threading model: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726624/specify-apartment-state-to-use-when-instantiating-out-of-proc-com-object/5727733#5727733