# Allowing connection to .NET COM server with mismatching integrity level

Tags: c#, .net, com, uac

I'm having an issue with a COM based client-server setup. The COM server is written in C# (.NET 4.0) and runs as a (registered) local server.

Depending on which application connects to the server, other clients will receive a **Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)**

The underlying issue is explained [here (in the section COM is integrity aware)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625962.aspx). The way I understand it, it is being caused by the fact that an elevated application creates the server with a higher integrity level. When another non-elevated application then connects, it is not allowed to connect to the same instance. The same happens when a non-elevated application creates the process, followed an elevated application connecting.

I've tried to implement the solution described on the [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625962.aspx): modifying the registry to set a security descriptor that should allow all clients to connect. There is a [code sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679687.aspx) in C++, but this does effectively the same thing in .NET:

```
// Security Descriptor with NO_EXECUTE_UP
var sd = new RawSecurityDescriptor("O:BAG:BAD:(A;;0xb;;;WD)S:(ML;;NX;;;LW)");
byte[] securityDescriptor = new Byte[sd.BinaryLength];
sd.GetBinaryForm(securityDescriptor, 0);

RegistryKey key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("AppID\\{APP-ID-GUID}", true);
if (key == null)
{
    key = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey("AppID\\{APP-ID-GUID}");
}

using (key)
{
    key.SetValue("LaunchPermission", securityDescriptor, RegistryValueKind.Binary);
}
```

However, this does not have the desired effect. When the second client tries to create an instance of the object in question, Windows tries to launch a separate instance of my COM Server, but the server prevents two instances from running as the same user. Given the permissions I've set, I would not expect a second instance to launch in the first place.

Since one of the client applications is running in Medium IL and the other in High IL, I also experimented with variants on the [mandatory label](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625958.aspx), like:

```
O:BAG:BAD:(A;;0xb;;;WD)S:(ML;;NX;;;ME)
O:BAG:BAD:(A;;0xb;;;WD)S:(ML;;NX;;;LW)(ML;;NX;;;ME)(ML;;NX;;;HI)
```

I've also tried setting the `ROTFlags` registry key to 0x1 (ROTFLAGS_ALLOWANYCLIENT) as suggested on the page, still no change in behavior.

I've established that the LaunchPermission registry value is being used in some way. I cannot discover where it's being read using Process Monitor, but when I use the `dcomcnfg.exe` tool to set the same key, I can force the server to fail loading by denying launch permissions.

I would like to point out that my server process does not need elevation. How do I make both elevated and non-elevated processes capable of connecting to a single server instance?

Comment: Is the server registered in the registry?

Comment: @tyranid: Yes, and it has an AppID. I've updated my code to write a registry key instead, because the MSDN solution mentions using this solution.

Comment: I guess it is a stupid question but have you tried setting AccessPermission? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688679%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @tyranid: Setting it to what? The MSDN page only mentions needing LaunchPermissions to get around this particular issue?

Comment: Well setting it to a similar security descriptor, I doubt it would make a difference but certainly when used in services exposing COM servers it is important to determine access for lower privileged clients. Tbh what is your registration mode? Do you _need_ to only create a single instance of the server executable?

Comment: @tyranid: Activate as Activator, if that's what you're referring to. And yes, I need a single instance. I could theoretically make things work with two instances if these instances were to communicate with each other, but it would make it a whole lot more complicated. I tried also setting Access Permissions, but this has no effect.

Comment: (outside the box question) Is COM a requirement?  I've had similar situations before.  I chickened-out and made a wrapper (COM+/WCF) and called the wrapper.

Comment: @tgolisch: There are additional functional requirements that effectively make COM a requirement. I would have preferred not using COM myself :)

Comment: "The same happens when a non-elevated application creates the process, followed [by] an elevated application connecting." This scenario shouldn't fall foul of integrity control... are you sure there isn't some other issue in play? How does the app fail in this scenario?

Comment: How is the COM server declared? Is it Singleton?

Comment: Try this article, not sure if threading is applicable but might give you some food for thought: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092523/how-to-mark-net-objects-exposed-to-com-interop-as-single-threaded

Answer (score 1):

According to [Windows Vista Security Model Analysis](http://www.symantec.com/avcenter/reference/Windows_Vista_Security_Model_Analysis.pdf) you will need to use shared objects such as a named pipe to go between the different IL. Also, the shared object should have an IL equivalent to your lowest IL being used.

Answer (score 0):

you have to Set Debug option to Any cpu in VS.