# Run a COM Service as System

Tags: winapi, com, dcom

How do I run a COM service as System and allow any client from any security context to connect to it?

I have an .exe that hosts my class object by calling `CoRegisterClassObject`. When I run the .exe as an Administrator, the same Administrator account can interact with it just fine. When I run the .exe as System, the Administrator account fails when calling `CoCreateInstance` with error `0x80040154`.

UPDATE:

I've made some progress. In the COM service I register my class factory in the running object table with the `ROTFLAGS_ALLOWANYCLIENT` flag. In the client I use the running object table's `GetObject` method to get a pointer to the class factory. This allows me to access the service when it runs as an Administrator from a non-Administrator account. However, when it runs as System, a non-System client's `CoCreateInstance` call fails with `0x80070005`. I suspect this issue is related to the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12039624/allowing-connection-to-net-com-server-with-mismatching-integrity-level).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by doing the following in the COM service:

1. Calling CoInitializeSecurity in such a way to allow everyone to connect:

   ```
   hresult = CoInitializeSecurity(
   NULL,
   -1,
   NULL,
   NULL,
   RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_NONE,
   RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IDENTIFY,
   NULL,
   0,
   NULL);
   ```
2. Registering the class factory in the running object table, specifying ROTFLAGS_ALLOWANYCLIENT:

   ```
   hresult = pIRunningObjectTable->Register(
       ROTFLAGS_ALLOWANYCLIENT |ROTFLAGS_REGISTRATIONKEEPSALIVE,
       pClassFactory,
       pIMoniker,
       &dwROTRegister);
   ```

And doing the following in the COM client:

1. Accessing the class factory from the running object table:

   ```
   hresult = pIRunningObjectTable->GetObjectW(pIMoniker, &pIUnknown);
   hresult = pIUnknown->QueryInterface(IID_IClassFactory, (PVOID *)&pIClassFactory);
   ```

I had to configure some registry settings to get it work correctly. Setting `HKCR\AppID\<guid>\LocalService` *prevented* it from working, so I do *not* have it defined. I set `HKCR\AppID\<guid>\RunAs` to `NT Authority\System`.